# Workspace Add On does not appear in sidebar (but does for Test Deploy)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I developed and published a Workspace Add-on for my organization (i.e. non-public) for sheets and docs. My admin has approved it and accounts in my org can install it.

The problem is that the icon does not appear in the side menu when over a sheet or doc. However, it does when I use a Test Deploy which I find weird.

For what its worth, it does appear in the Extensions top menu (but my UX does not work from there).

Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bi9C.png)

```
{
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#079838"
      },
      "logoUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/student_report_logo/Frame%201-4.png",
      "name": "Create Student Reports",
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://docs.google.com/"
      ]
    },
    "docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildHomepage"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildHomepage"
      }
    }
  },
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
}
```

I tried various versions of the homepage trigger in the manifest without change. In truth, that would only be called AFTER being clicked in the side menu.

Comment: I figured it out. When updating a published add-on, you need to update the version number on the App Configuration page of the [Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk) to match the new version number from AppsScript **Deploy > Manage deployments**.

[In the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on), it says to do this for Editor Add-ons but its required for non-Editor Add-ons as well. I left feedback so maybe they will update it.